# How to derive one column from two columns based on logical expressions in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I would like to derive one additional column from two columns based on some logical statements:

```
table
id col1 col additionalcol
1    a        a
2    b    c   c
3    d    e   e
4         f   f
5    g    me  g
6    i    me  i
7    j    l   l
8    k    m   m
9    n    me  n
10   o    p   p
```

I would like to derive an `additionalcol` based on the statement:

```
        `if 
            col is empty  or me then
                take col1
        else    
            take col
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ternary operator (conditional):

```
(col == null || col=="me") ? col1 : col
```

Comment: Do I have to use the "Derived Column Transformation"? If so, how to select on "Derived Column Name" and "Derived Column" ?

Comment: Yes, enter any name you like for Derived Column Name, and choose "Add as new column" for Derived Column.